# (C++) Pass 'this' to a static method as a default parameter

Tags: c++

Clearly doing something like `static void DoSomething(ClassPointer* MyPtr = this)` wouldn't work, because a static method has no `this`, however when I call this `DoSomething` I am always passing the `this` from the class calling it, I'd like to not have to put it in every time.

If there was some way to get a reference to the class calling that static method from inside the method itself then that would work, but AFAIK there isn't.

What options do I have available?

Comment: you could use a macro

Comment: If you're always passing 'this', why is it a static member function?

Comment: If you always call the static method with an instance, why just make it a non-static method?

Comment: It's being called from various classes across a larger project, the instance of that class calling it is important

Comment: @Vii Whether it is being called from "various classes" or not, the static method specifies some type in the signature for the argument that is the "this".  And that's just one class (base class?).  What is being asked is why if you have a common behavior to apply to instances of this type, you aren't making it a class method--maybe a virtual one--of that type (instead of DoSomething being a static method of a completely different type?).  You should probably elaborate on your situation more concretely.

Comment: @HostileFork The static method is for printing information for debugging, and needs to know if the class calling it exists on the server or the client. That's what it's checking on the class that is passed. Every class needs to be able to call it, and pass their own instance of their class to this static method. I want to skip the requirement to add the `this` parameter every time I use the static method.

Comment: @Vii This means that your `ClassPointer` (or whatever) has an `->isOnServer()` method.  So this is a common definition they are all willing to have and offer.  The question is, so long as you have a common place to put a definition of `->isOnServer()`, why not right next to that have `->DoSomething()` in the same method list... and get the `this` pointer normally.  It could call `OtherClass::DoSomethingCore(this)` if you wanted to put some implementation code in another class, but that would be written just once.

Comment: @HostileFork It would require modifying the API which isn't viable for this. If the conversation is going on this direction then I guess it isn't possible to do precisely what I'm asking.

Comment: @Vii You could use a macro.

Comment: @immibis how would the macro look for this? I've used them but not for methods

Comment: @Vii #define SOMETHING() SomeClass::DoSomething(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a macro

```
#define DoSomethingX(...) DoSomething(this, __VA_ARGS__)
```

And call

```
StaticFunctionClass::DoSomethingX(par1, par2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the context of the requesting object to be passed as a reference, I would consider having the method be a non-static instance method. This way, you can reference the other instance members of the class within the method. If the behavior changes depending on the subclass class, perhaps you could use a virtual method that can be overridden.

Comment: I think he means that he has many different classes that all call this static method (like maybe it registers a callback listener) and that the class that the static method is in is not in the same inheritance hierarchy as the callers  - so you need to pass the pointer to the caller's class so that later the pointer passed in can be used to invoke a member function in the caller's class   If it was a member function then it would have to be in every inheritance hierarchy and not just the eventListener class.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Interesting.  Well c++ supports multiple inheritance so you could actually have a base implementation that could be extended by any class requiring it, couldn't you?  I like your idea about a callback approach.  Could also consider the visitor pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern